# Running a script on all nodes of Hadoop in Amazon EMR

Tags: hadoop, amazon-emr

How do you run a script on all nodes (master and slaves) on Amazon EMR, the script-runner.jar runs only on the Namenode.

Comment: Can you clarify if you are referring to running a script at bootstrap time, per @Paulo's answer below, or part way through a run? If the former, you should probably accept Paulo's answer.

Comment: I am having the same question, and bootstrap action is not a choice for me. How to use script-runner.jar to run a script on all nodes (master and slaves).

Answer (score 0):

You have the bootstrap option:

*You can use a bootstrap action to install additional software and to change the configuration of applications on the cluster. Bootstrap actions are scripts that are run on the cluster nodes when Amazon EMR launches the cluster. They run before Hadoop starts and before the node begins processing data. You can create custom bootstrap actions, or use predefined bootstrap actions provided by Amazon EMR.*

from the documentation: http://docs.aws.amazon.com/ElasticMapReduce/latest/DeveloperGuide/emr-plan-bootstrap.html

It's as simple as placing a script to do the copying into S3, and then if you're starting EMR from the command line, add a parameter like this:

```
--bootstrap-action 's3://my-bucket/boostrap.sh'
```

Or if you're doing it through the web interface, just enter the location of the file in  as a "Custom action" in "Bootstrap Actions".